# Google Dart visibility of methods and properties

Tags: dart

Just to avoid some misunderstanding, I know that Google Dart handles things on a library level and that private properties and methods can be identified with a underscore prefix.

Is this still up to date as of 2017? Are there any plans for adding object level visibility keywords like: private, protected or public?

I dont just want to do something random but im rather interested in best practices. The way I see it is: if I dont want class one to see what class two has then both must be in different libraries, those libraries then are part of a bigger package.

libraries = privacy between classes
packages = privacy between files

What about fine grained control of privacy? I mean  maybe there is 1 thing I want private. What about using visibility when using inheritance? I mean protected keywords can be really valuable.

Here a little example in one file:

```
class one {
  int n = 1;

  one() {
    var test = new two(n);
    print(test.showNumber());
  }
}

class two {
  int n = 2;

  two(n) {
    this.n += n;
  }

  int showNumber() {
    return n;
  }
}
```

As it stands now, both classes can do what they want.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Dart still has only library-level privacy.

Library-level privacy with identifiers starting with an underscore is also enforced at runtime.

The analyzer provides some additional features during static analysis which are ignored at runtime though.

Per convention also libraries inside `lib/src` are considered private, and should now be imported from other packages. <strike>The [linter](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/linter), a plugin for the analyzer notifies about violations.</strike> Seems to be part of the analyzer itself.

The [meta](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/meta) package provides some annotations that are supported by the analyzer.

- `@protected` produces a warning if public members are referenced by code from other libraries that is not within subclasses.
- `@visibleForTesting` produces a warning if public members are references by code that is not within the `test` directory (of the same package I assume) Not sure if the analyzer actually warns about violations yet, otherwise it's planned to do that.

As far as I remember there are some issues for more rules but not yet implemented.

From @lrn's comment below

> One reason for the current design is that Dart allows dynamic calls, even in strong mode. That means that `o.foo()` cannot be rejected based on "class level privacy" without retaining and checking extra information at runtime. With library/lexical based privacy, it's absolutely clear whether `o.foo()` or `o._foo()` is allowed (it always is, it's just that the latter can only refer to the `_foo` name of the same library). If Dart only had static resolution of identifiers, then it could use static information (like a `private` declaration) to reject at compile time without a runtime overhead.

Comment: Do you think their decision to avoid these keywords is good or bad? I thought they would have added these with Strong Mode.

Comment: I don't know if this was a deliberate decision. It might be caused by how Dart loads libraries (for example from HTTP URLs). Actually I missed protected and package private, but I'm perfectly fine with analyzer-only support to get notified about violations by the IDE but without enforcement at runtime. I'm sure they will improve here when the migration to strong mode and Dart 2.0 is completed.

Comment: I thought they already released strong mode. Never heared of plans for dart 2.0. As im aware dart is at 1.19 http://news.dartlang.org/

Comment: Strong mode isn't related to privacy, only to type annotations. Dart 2.0 was mentioned the first time about 2 years ago :D Dart 2.0 is IMHO mostly a release where changes they want to introduce are breaking changes. Breaking changes are not possible without increasing the major number in the version. It's not clear yet what exactly will make it into 2.0 - but they have some projects they are working on to figure out how well some features will work out and whether they are worth being added to the language.

Comment: One reason for the current design is that Dart allows *dynamic calls*, even in strong mode. That means that `o.foo()` cannot be rejected based on "class level privacy" without retaining and checking extra information at runtime. With library/lexical based privacy, it's absolutely clear whether `o.foo()` or `o._foo()` is allowed (it always is, it's just that the latter can only refer to the `_foo`  name of the same library). If Dart only had static resolution of identifiers, then it could use static information (like a `private` declaration) to reject at compile time without a runtime overhead.

Comment: @lrn Thanks a lot. Don't remember seeing this mentioned. I'll add it to my question to make it more prominent. I just assume that's fine with you ;-)